# Excel Formula for Inventory Tracking

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to track an inventory in a pharmacy. At a previous location, there was a nice excel set up. The important columns for this question include B being an RX number, C being an invoice, D being qty dispensed, E being qty received, and F being total. I have been trying to put the formula in column F.

I need formula that if there is text in cell B3, then F2 minus D3 will give a new total in F3. And then beyond that if there is text in cell C4, then F3 plus E4 will give a new total in F4. Essentially, if there is a text in column B it needs to subtract the quantity in column D from total in column F and then give a new total in that row. If there is a text in column C, it needs to add the quantity from column E to the total in column F and give a new total in that row. I want the total to auto-populate, given what I put in columns B&D or columns C&E.

[image]

Comment: so you want a running balance in column F

Comment: Hi @StepP your data set principally needs little corrections Qty. Received (should in col D) must before Qty. Dispatched (should in col E), since the formula should be `(Opening Stock + Qty. Received ) - Qty. Dispatched`. in F3.  `=($F2 + $D3)-$E3`, and fill it down.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can use the below formula in Cell F3 and drag down.

```
=$F$2+SUM($E$3:E3)-SUM($D$3:D3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If B&D and C&E have content at the same time, you may try the following formula, and drop down.
`=IF(A3="","",F2-D3+E3)`

[image]